# Rendering a partial causes user with id 1 to be last only on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view, partial-views, railstutorial.org

I am working through Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails tutorial and came across an issue I can't resolve.

My issue is with the page that lists all Users. Locally, the code works fine and the users are all listed in order. When I deploy to heroku, however, the user with id = 1 is shown last, after user with id = 100. What is causing this? Here is the relevant code:

***users_controller.rb***

```
def index
    @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page])
end
```

***index.html.erb***

```
<%= provide(:title, 'All users') %>
<h1>All users</h1>

<%= will_paginate %>

<ul class="users">
    <%= render @users %>
</ul>

<%= will_paginate %>
```

***_user.html.erb***

```
<li>
    <%= gravatar_for user, size: 52 %>
    <%= link_to user.name, user %>
    <% if current_user.admin? && !current_user?(user) %>
    |  <%= link_to "delete", user, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %>
    <% end %>
</li>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sort users by id in your controller to prevent this behaviour:

```
def index
  @users = User.order('id ASC').paginate(page: params[:page])
end
```

Comment: And to be more specific, I think that's because you use PostgreSQL and it doesn't have default ordering by id.

Comment: Makes sense because the local environment is using sqlite3 in the tutorial. Thank you both!

Comment: Out of curiosity, would another way to do this be to add `default_scope -> order('name ASC')` to the user model?

Comment: @SpencerMoran yes, `default_scope` is an option.